# show/hide form depending on dropdown

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I am trying to show one specific form depending of the dropbox choice. This is what I have so far:
HTML:

```
                <select id='selector'>
                    <option value='option-1' id="opt1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value='option-2' id="opt2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value='option-3' id="opt3">Option 3</option>
                </select>



                <form action="" method="post" id="form1" class="form">
                    <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_2" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_3" name="input_3" type="text"/>
                </form>​

                <form action="" method="post" id="form2" class="form">
                    <input id="input_4" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_5" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_6" name="input_3" type="text"/>
                </form>​

                <form action="" method="post" id="form3" class="form">
                    <input id="input_7" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_8" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                    <input id="input_9" name="input_3" type="text"/>
                </form>​
```

and jquery:

```
    $select.change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "opt1"){
            if($('#form1').is(":hidden")){
                $('#form1').show();            
            }        
            $('#form2').hide();
            $('#form3').hide(); 
        }
        if($(this).val() == "opt2"){
            if($('#form2').is(":hidden")){
                $('#form2').show();            
            }
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form3').hide(); 
        }
        if($(this).val() == "option3"){
            if($('#form3').is(":hidden")){
                $('#form3').show();            
            }
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form2').hide(); 
        }     
    });
```

I want to use it for different contact types, eg. "get a quote", "general enquiry", "post a feedback" - unless you have better idea of doing this. Appreciate your time and help.

jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/cBCTm/)

The problem here is that this doesn't work. It displays all forms in the same time and #selector doesn't affect the visibility of any of them at all.

Comment: I'm not getting what is the question here :O/

Comment: @cacho - this just doesn't work. I tried to figure out whats wrong with it but it's just not working. it displays all forms, where it should display only 1 depending of the choice made by dropdown.

Comment: @cacho I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/cBCTm/1/

Comment: your testing against the id not the value... a bit messy as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after -

```
$(function() {
    var $select = $("#selector");
    $select.change(function () {
        if ($('#selector option:selected').attr("id") == "opt1") {
            if ($('#form1').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#form1').fadeIn(400);
            }
            $('#form2').hide();
            $('#form3').hide();
        }
        if ($('#selector option:selected').attr("id") == "opt2") {
            if ($('#form2').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#form2').fadeIn(400);
            }
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form3').hide();
        }
        if ($('#selector option:selected').attr("id") == "opt3") {
            if ($('#form3').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#form3').fadeIn(400);
            }
            $('#form1').hide();
            $('#form2').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RY2vD/

/edit

Here is how I would approach this (a tad bit of refactoring) -

```
$(function () {
    hideForms();
    $("#form1").show();
    $("#selector").change(function () {
        hideForms();
        if ($('#selector option:selected').attr("id") == "opt1") {
            $('#form1').fadeIn(400);
        } else if ($('#selector option:selected').attr("id") == "opt2") {
            $('#form2').fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            $('#form3').fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
});

function hideForms() {
    $(".form").hide();
    // maybe some other stuff to do here
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpL49/3/

Comment: You're welcome, you can mark it as the answer if you like :~)

Comment: I will. Is there a way of instead of just showing the proper form - fade it in? Just want to try how it looks.

Comment: Sure, I added the fadeIn.  You can pass it an integer for how many milliseconds it takes to complete the fadeIn.

Comment: great work. I know about ms :) but thanks. I do understand everything from this, but it's a big difference between building something from scratch and re-creating or understanding it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I hope my question will be useful for others.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski I added some more to my initial answer to provide a different approach that does the same thing with less code and will be faster.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<select id='selector' onload="typeres()" onchange="typeres()">
   <option value='option-1' id="opt1">Option 1</option>
   <option value='option-2' id="opt2">Option 2</option>
   <option value='option-3' id="opt3">Option 3</option>
</select>



            <form action="" method="post" id="form1" class="form">
                <input id="input_1" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_2" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_3" name="input_3" type="text"/>
            </form>​

            <form action="" method="post" id="form2" class="form">
                <input id="input_4" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_5" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_6" name="input_3" type="text"/>
            </form>​

            <form action="" method="post" id="form3" class="form">
                <input id="input_7" name="input_1" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_8" name="input_2" type="text"/>
                <input id="input_9" name="input_3" type="text"/>
            </form>
```

**Javascript and jQuery**

```
function typeres(){
  $('.form').css('visibility','hidden');
  var e=document.getElementById("selector");
  if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value=="option-1"){
      $('#form1').css('visibility','visible');
  }else if(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value=="option-1"){
      $('#form2').css('visibility','visible');                                             
  }else{
      $('#form3').css('visibility','visible');
  }
}
```

Hope this might help..

Comment: Instead of `$('#form1').css('visibility','visible');` you can use this giving some effect `$('#form1').fadeIn(slow);` and fadeOut()

Comment: trying this one as well in jsfiddle but doesnt work like should, maybe i do something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/RY2vD/3/

Comment: This is good, just check for 'option-2' in that second else if

Comment: @Ross - I missed that. it works fine then. the only thing is that leaves a gap after opt1 and opt2 instead of replacing the actual form. so what i really want is to have a form just under the #selector. thanks