# Jquery tabs functionality in dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

Ho to change the Jquery tabs content using select box

Here the Fiddle link that i have tried

[**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/mehar/5KgHv/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: See [this](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478433/2260614)

***[`Demo Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/5KgHv/4/)***
*jQuery Code*

```
function typeres() {
    $('.tabs').hide();
    var e = document.getElementById("tabSelector");
    if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "tabs-1") {
        $('#tabs-1').fadeIn();
    } else if (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "tabs-2") {
        $('#tabs-2').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#tabs-3').fadeIn();
    }
}
```

*It is not based on jQuery UI*, it is an alternative method of what you want to achieve...