# Using a selection from a drop down list to show relevent information

Tags: jquery, html

To save space I need to add a drop down menu on my page that, when a location is selected, the address of that location is displayed in a field next to the drop-down menu. They can repeatedly use that drop down to get addresses instead of me having to list them all. I have been searching around for a tutorial that will show how to do something like this without luck and its probably because I am not search using the correct terms.

I have done something SIMILAR in a way to this before but I was populating another field in a form with the text that was selected. With this I need to populate with an address assigned to that location name.

I am sorry if this has been covered before here, any help would be much appreciated...is there any tutorial out there that shows how to go about doing this? There aren't a lot of locations so if there is a simple way of doing this without having to resort to databases and the like, that would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code and attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: [___Check this answer___](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17478433/2260614)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. Put the addresses in as values and the location in as option text.

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="location" name="location">
    <option value="dfsdfsdf">test</option>
    <option value="sdfsdfsdfsd">test2</option>
    <!-- Add more options -->
</select>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var location = document.getElementById("location");
        location.addEventListener('change',function(){
            document.getElementById("address").value = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this exact type of thing but have the address text load into a DIV where I can have more control of the formatting (not scroll bars and the ability to control color and fonts)

Comment: You can move it into whatever container you want. Change the input to a div and assign the innerHTML instead of the value.